# oauth2 token store clash (JPA vs inMemory)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, oauth, spring-boot

Hello I got problem with refreshing token in OAuth2.

To obtain fresh token, I am using following request:
{{host}}/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=[refresh_token_obtained_from_authorization]

The response which I got is:

```
{
  "error": "server_error",
  "error_description": "UserDetailsService is required."
}
```

in logs I can see:

```
2016-10-24 23:01:41.166 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.refreshAccessToken]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '',+org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidTokenException,+org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidGrantException
2016-10-24 23:01:41.166 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@54164e7a] for JPA transaction
2016-10-24 23:01:41.166 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2016-10-24 23:01:41.166 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@5ad1aa88]
2016-10-24 23:01:41.167 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider
2016-10-24 23:01:41.167 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] p.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider : PreAuthenticated authentication request: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@7a6d6be4: Principal: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@95dbc1ee: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@1c27dc33: Username: forkflit; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: FORK_FLIT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: {grant_type=password, scope=trust, username=forkflit}; Granted Authorities: FORK_FLIT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: FORK_FLIT
2016-10-24 23:01:41.167 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction rollback
2016-10-24 23:01:41.167 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@54164e7a]
2016-10-24 23:01:41.167 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : rolling back
2016-10-24 23:01:41.167 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@54164e7a] after transaction
2016-10-24 23:01:41.167 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
2016-10-24 23:01:41.167 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UserDetailsService is required.
2016-10-24 23:01:41.167 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2Exception> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.handleException(java.lang.Exception) throws java.lang.Exception
2016-10-24 23:01:41.167  INFO 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: IllegalStateException, UserDetailsService is required.
```

When I try to put refresh token inside body: `{"refresh_token":"[refresh_token]"}` in response I got:

```
{
  "error": "server_error",
  "error_description": null
}
```

and in log:

```
2016-10-24 23:05:19.449 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices.refreshAccessToken]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '',+org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidTokenException,+org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidGrantException
2016-10-24 23:05:19.449 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@386e5658] for JPA transaction
2016-10-24 23:05:19.449 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
2016-10-24 23:05:19.449 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@36a9af25]
2016-10-24 23:05:19.449 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction rollback
2016-10-24 23:05:19.449 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@386e5658]
2016-10-24 23:05:19.449 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : rolling back
2016-10-24 23:05:19.450 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@386e5658] after transaction
2016-10-24 23:05:19.450 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
2016-10-24 23:05:19.450 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]: java.lang.NullPointerException
2016-10-24 23:05:19.450 DEBUG 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2Exception> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.handleException(java.lang.Exception) throws java.lang.Exception
2016-10-24 23:05:19.450  INFO 48384 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: NullPointerException, null
```

Interesting thing is, that spring is doing something with JPA, while in my configuration I am using `inMemory()`... What Spring wants from DB?

This is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private UsersService service = new UsersService();

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManager;


    @Override
    public void configure( AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {
            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                logger.info("Authentication!");
                return authenticationManager.getOrBuild().authenticate(authentication);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("myApp")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("write", "read", "trust")
                .secret("123456").accessTokenValiditySeconds( 200 );
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (username) -> {
            return service.getByName(username).map(account -> new User(account.getUsername(), account.getPassword(), account.getAuthorities())).orElseThrow(
                    () -> new RuntimeException("User not found")
            );
        };
    }
}
```

In logs I see that Bean is created:

```
2016-10-24 22:53:49.648 DEBUG 48384 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'userDetailsService'
2016-10-24 22:53:49.648 DEBUG 48384 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'userDetailsService'
2016-10-24 22:53:49.648 DEBUG 48384 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2016-10-24 22:53:49.648 DEBUG 48384 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'OAuth2Configuration'
2016-10-24 22:53:49.653 DEBUG 48384 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Eagerly caching bean 'userDetailsService' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2016-10-24 22:53:49.654 DEBUG 48384 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2016-10-24 22:53:49.654 DEBUG 48384 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2016-10-24 22:53:49.655 DEBUG 48384 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'userDetailsService'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's related to any JPA or InMemory stuff.

For first error for UserDetailService, based on the logs you posted, simply means you don't have proper UserDetailsService implementation injected. UserDetailsService is just interface. I don't know what else you did for configuration, but error definitely says Spring can't find proper UserDetailsService injected. In the Oauth2Configuration, I see you instantiated UsersService that I think it's your custom implementation for UserDetailService interface?

For second error, I see `org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` in the log, which means, I guess, you posted request with GET but server expect POST or vice versa. Check what HTTP method you are using, and what sever code is expecting to get.

Try to change

```
endpoints.authenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {
        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            logger.info("Authentication!");
            return authenticationManager.getOrBuild().authenticate(authentication);
        }
    });
```

to

```
endpoints.authenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {
        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            logger.info("Authentication!");
            return authenticationManager.getOrBuild().authenticate(authentication);
            }
        })
    .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);
```

at the end of the endpoints configuration and see if makes difference.

Comment: I don't got one thing... If I would doesn't have UserDetailsService I should not be able to retrieve access_token using user credentials as well as using refresh_token (using credentials works correctly)

Comment: Then it shouldn't be because of missing UserDetailsService, just missing configuration that server side doesn't take the HTTP method that your client requests?